# Moving Items Between Lists in Python

Tags: python, list

So I have recently began programming in earnest with Automate the Boring the Stuff, and after reading the chapters on basic syntax decided to start working on a Blackjack game. However, I ran into a problem when dealing out the cards. I have the main deck

```
deck=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'J','Q','K','A']*4
```

and have a separate empty list called `playerHand`. I understand that I can use .append and random.choice to pick a card at random and add it to `playerHand[]`, but this doesn't remove the cards from `deck[]`.

The only way I could think of would be to randomly generate a number between one and the amount of cards left in deck, set a variable to that number, set another variable to the card at that index, add that card to `playerHand[]`, and then finally delete the card at that index in `deck[]`.

Is there a way to do it that doesn't involve 2 temporary variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use `list.pop`.

`list.pop` will remove the value at the given index and return it:

```
In [105]: l = [1, 2, 3, 4]

In [106]: l.pop(2)  # here 2 is the index, at index 2 we have value 3
Out[106]: 3

In [107]: l
Out[107]: [1, 2, 4]
```

Note that, by default `pop` will *pop* the value at the last index (`l[-1]`).

---

So, in your case, you can do a `random.shuffle`-ing of the list and `pop`:

```
In [108]: deck=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'J','Q','K','A']*4

In [109]: random.shuffle(deck)

In [110]: deck.pop()
Out[110]: 7
```

Comment: Only confusing part for someone new to Python is that you are popping '2' which, in fact, pops '3'. This is, of course, because the list index starts with '0'. I would add this explanation to your answer to be more complete.

Comment: @jamescampbell Edited. Look okay now?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of randomly choosing an *element*, randomly choose an *index*.

You can then remove the *element* at that *index* and append it to another `list` in one single line with [`pop`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types):

```
>>> import random
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b = []
>>> b.append(a.pop(random.randint(0, len(a))))
>>> 
>>> a
[1, 3, 4]
>>> b
[2]
```